# Android Studio editor grayed out

Tags: android-studio

I have an issue with Android Studio.

After few seconds i've opened my project, the text editor of a specific java file (MainActivity.java) gets grayed out and i cannot do anything. Like this:

[image]

I've tried to clear caches and restart -> no luck

I've tried to reimport the full project from git -> no luck

I've tried to fully reinstall the IDE and also change the version, from Electric Eel to Giraffe -> No luck

I'm running out of ideas. Has someone had the same problem and found a solution?